# How to send a SMS in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Model-View-Controller 4 and I want to add some Extra functions to my app...I want my app to be able to send a client a SMS .

I am able to send an email from my app.Is it the same concept?

How do I Code it ?Please Help

Comment: what have you tried?  What SMS library are you using? Its a bit more complicated than Email, as at some point you need to connect to the GSM network.

Comment: What MVC framework are you using? ASP.NET MVC, Zend Framework, etc... MVC is a programming standard, and does not describe an on specific tool, framework, or program. Please edit your question to be more complete, otherwise, it will likely be closed and go unanswered.

Comment: @cjb110 Not necessarily. There are SMS gateways which let you send an SMS through an API, or even let you send an e-mail which they convert to an SMS.

Comment: @GolezTrol I realised that, I'm wasn't sure if the poster does though!

Comment: @Kereshan The fact that your application is built according to MVC is nice, but isn't in any way related to sending an SMS.

Answer (score 3):

You can send an SMS to a user via a traditional email, as long as you know the domain name of the provider the user is using. Here is a list of domain names of various cell phone carriers: http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

You will need to ask the user for his or her carrier, and route the email to the appropriate domain. So, for example, if my phone number was 123-555-6789 (US number) and I was using Verizon (in the US), I would send an email to:

```
1235556789@vtext.com
```

When the user receives the SMS on his or her phone, the sending "phone number" will look a little strange, since you sent it via email, but it will work. I've done this before.

Since I don't know your specific MVC framework, I can't provide a concrete example, but I'm sure you can find lots of examples on how to send an email with your specific framework.

As GolezTrol mentioned, MVC is not required to send an email/SMS, it's just a programming model.

Comment: Nice feature. Is it common to ask that in the US? I don't think this is a feature that all providers (world-wide) would support. I've never heard about this in the Netherlands, where I live, and I cannot find any reference to it. And though it is common to ask for a cell phone number, I don't recall anyone ever asking about my carrier. But it's a good start.

Comment: @GolezTrol Perhaps not, but it's a start. There are certainly other options and providers, if you are willing to pay for them. [http://mashable.com/2008/04/19/send-text-messages/] If you have ever used Google Voice, Google will ask you to specify your specific cellphone carrier in order to set up your specific GV account. So, given that Google asks for this kind of information, I don't think it would be too unreasonable for his application to ask.

Comment: Im using entity frame work with a repository pattern

Comment: Ok, Entity Framework is for communicating with a database, but isn't in itself an MVC framework. However, it is a .NET technology, and the most common MVC framework for .NET is ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5. Can you tell which one you are using? The repository is just for holding your code, and doesn't have anything to do with a framework.

Answer (score 1):

you can send Email in your app so you can send SMS, it is the same concept.
If you want to send SMS you need:

- Connect with some SMS gateway via API (you can search in Google about SMS gateway)
- Or send AT Command to SMS/GPRS modem which connect with your computer (or server)
- Or connect SMS/GPRS modem with your computer (or server) and then install software like

NowSMS or Kannel to build your server into SMSGateway. and use your app connect to the SMSGateway.